# Auto expand DIV with border images

Tags: css, xhtml

I have a DIV who's borders are made up of images. What I'm trying to do is have this DIV auto expand (in height only) whenever the content does not fit the content area. Otherwise it should just use the min-height. Here is my markup:

XHTML:

```
<div id="alerts">
    <div id="alerts-top"></div>
    <div id="alerts-left"></div>

    <div id="alerts-content">
        <div id="alerts-header">
            <p>Alerts</p>
        </div>

        <div id="alerts-main">
            <!-- content in here -->
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="alerts-right"></div>
    <div id="alerts-bottom"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#alerts { float: left; width: 267px; height: 200px; }

#alerts #alerts-top { float: left; background: url(../images/alerts-top.png) no-repeat; height: 12px; min-width: 257px; }
#alerts #alerts-left { float: left; background: url(../images/alerts-left.png) repeat-y; height: 100%; width: 12px; }

#alerts #alerts-content { float: left; min-width: 239px; height: 206px; min-height: 206px; }
#alerts #alerts-content #alerts-header { background: url(../images/alerts-bell.png) no-repeat; height: 20px; width: auto; padding: 10px; }
#alerts #alerts-content #alerts-main { background-color: #FFFFFF; height: auto; }

#alerts #alerts-right { float: left; background: url(../images/alerts-right.png) repeat-y; height: 100%; width: 12px; }
#alerts #alerts-bottom { float: left; background: url(../images/alerts-bottom.png) no-repeat; height: 11px; width: 258px; }
```

This isn't working for me - there is a gap between the bottom border and the left and right borders. The content area is `#alerts-main`.

Comment: Whats the full url of your images please?

Comment: Sorry, I'm currently developing on my local server.

Comment: height of the 'alerts' div is 200px and 'alerts-content' is 206px,  as left and right are 100% it will render according to parent's height thats causing a gap for you.

Comment: It's going to be hard to help, without seeing your border images. Can you upload them to a webserver?

Comment: @AlexThomas use color instead..

Comment: try adding a screen shot if you are building locally

Answer (score 0):

Try this for `#alerts-bottom`:

```
#alerts #alerts-bottom {
    float: left;
    background: url(../images/alerts-bottom.png) no-repeat;
    height: 11px;
    width: 258px;
    margin-top: -9px;
}
```

With a negative value for `margin-top` property you control how the `div` will be displayed (in this case you'll force the `#alerts-bottom` `div` to be rendered `9px` above the default display).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

After a "five minutes" consideration I've wrote this code and it will do what you want. Just change the styles to add the images as backgrounds. First the CSS:

```
#wrapper { position: relative; width: 500px; min-height: 350px; }
#alerts { position: relative; height: 50px; background-color: red; width: 90%; text-align: center; margin: auto; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px; }
#top-margin { position: absolute; height: 10px; top: 0; background-color: gray; width: 100%; }
#right-margin { position: absolute; width: 10px; right: 0; background-color: gray; height: 100%; }
#bottom-margin { position: absolute; height: 10px; bottom: 0; background-color: gray; width: 100%; }
#left-margin { position: absolute; width: 10px; left: 0; background-color: gray; height: 100%; }
#content { text-align: justify; padding: 65px 20px 20px 20px; }
```

And the HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="top-margin">
        <div id="alerts">Alerts alerts alerts</div>
    </div>
    <div id="right-margin"></div>
    <div id="bottom-margin"></div>
    <div id="left-margin"></div>

    <div id="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet etc...</div>
</div>
```

The `#wrapper`'s height will expand as more text is added. Sorry that I've changed the names of the Ids and justified the text. But that can easily be remedied.